# Gradle download certain dependency jars to build file and strip version

Tags: gradle

I'm looking for something similar to the Maven dependencies plugin in Gradle.

I want to download some of my dependencies to the build folder and strip the version number from each jar file downloaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be easy:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'dependencies'
   rename '(.*)-[0-9]+\\..*.jar', '$1.jar'
}
```

Comment: I used the following regex for removing the version: `rename '(.*)-[0-9]+\\..*.jar', '$1.jar'`

Comment: For the record, I used `rename '(.*)-[a-z0-9\\.]+.jar', '$1.jar`. That seems to cover version numbers that contain letters (e.g. git commit hashes if you're using jitpack for some dependencies)

Comment: @Miguel, thanks for the input. If you found the answer useful, upvote it please.